# R: splitting columns in two but keep the rest

Tags: r, split, strsplit

Hi I have this table here:

| variable | level | vaccinated = 0 (n=16455) | vaccinated = 1 (n=1297 | Total (n=17752) | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sex | M | 8,586 (52.2) | 714(55.1) | 9,3023 (12,1) | 1,22 |
|  | F | 1,2323(12,1) | 1,2323(12,1) | 9,3023 (12,1) | 1,223 |
| Agegroup | 0-15 | 12,313(9,1) | 1,2323(12,1) | 9,3023 (12,1) | 12,23 |
|  | 16-20 | 12,313(9,1) | 1,2323(12,1) | 9,3023 (12,1) | 12.34 |
|  | 21-25 | 12,313(9,1) | 1,2323(12,1) | 9,3023 (12,1) | 12.33 |

I have a lot more categories under variable - but i just showed a bi ofthe table with artificial data.

I wish to split the columns vaccinated = 0 (n=16455), vaccinated = 1 (n=1297) and Total (n=17752)  into two columns so the frequency and percentages in these variables are seperated in their own column - should be like this:

| variable | level | vaccinated = 0 (n=16455) | pct. = 0 | vaccinated = 1 (n=1297 | pct. = 1 | Total (n=17752) | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sex | M | 8,586 | 52.2 | 714 | 55.1 | 9,3023 (12,1) | 1,22 |
|  | F | 1,2323 | 12,1 | 1,2323 | 12,1 | 9,3023 (12,1) | 1,223 |
| Agegroup | 0-15 | 12,313 | 9,1 | 1,2323 | 12,1 | 9,3023 (12,1) | 12,23 |
|  | 16-20 | 12,313 | 9,1 | 1,2323 | 12,1 | 9,3023 (12,1) | 12.34 |
|  | 21-25 | 12,313 | 9,1 | 1,2323 | 12,1 | 9,3023 (12,1) | 12.33 |

And then the same for the Total (n=17752)...

how can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```r
tmp <- do.call(cbind.data.frame,
  unname(Map(function(x,nm) strcapture("(.*?)\\s?\\((.*?)\\)", x,
                                       proto = setNames(rep("", 2), paste0(nm, c("","_pct")))),
             dat[,3:5],
             c("vacc0", "vacc1", "Total"))))
tmp
#    vacc0 vacc0_pct  vacc1 vacc1_pct  Total Total_pct
# 1  8,586      52.2    714      55.1 9,3023      12,1
# 2 1,2323      12,1 1,2323      12,1 9,3023      12,1
# 3 12,313       9,1 1,2323      12,1 9,3023      12,1
# 4 12,313       9,1 1,2323      12,1 9,3023      12,1
# 5 12,313       9,1 1,2323      12,1 9,3023      12,1
```

With this, we can bind it back into the original data:

```r
cbind(dat[,1:2], tmp, dat[,6,drop=FALSE])
#   variable level  vacc0 vacc0_pct  vacc1 vacc1_pct  Total Total_pct p-value
# 1      Sex     M  8,586      52.2    714      55.1 9,3023      12,1    1,22
# 2              F 1,2323      12,1 1,2323      12,1 9,3023      12,1   1,223
# 3 Agegroup  0-15 12,313       9,1 1,2323      12,1 9,3023      12,1   12,23
# 4          16-20 12,313       9,1 1,2323      12,1 9,3023      12,1   12.34
# 5          21-25 12,313       9,1 1,2323      12,1 9,3023      12,1   12.33
```